# bypassing body unload ="window.print" while scraping the page

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the page which loads after the print popup is gone(canceled).

testing the xpath to the product name and ID (as shown in the screenshot) with any possible combinations so far return empty and I suspect that print popup js is the reason.

Any tips about how to bypass the print popup would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Here is the screenshot from the DOM:

[image]

Comment: Show the code you are using first.

Comment: Haven't written spider yet, was testing simple one line xpath which returns empty []. 

this is one of them:

 'sel.xpath('//table[@class="tab_product_info_details"]')'

Comment: Ok, could you share the link (for testing the xpath)?

Comment: http://www.mymarket.ge/classified_details_print.php?product_id=5827165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example spider for getting the text you've highlighted on the screenshot:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MarketItem(Item):
    name = Field()


class MarketSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "market"
    allowed_domains = ["mymarket.ge"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mymarket.ge/classified_details_print.php?product_id=5827165"]

    def parse(self, response):
        contacts = Selector(response)

        item = MarketItem()
        item['name'] = contacts.xpath('//td[@class="product_info_details_text"]/b/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        return item
```

this gets an item:

```
{'name': u'Nokia asha 515 dual sim'}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! It certainly does! I'm still struggling to establish the main xpath as there are other items to be scraped(like ID and so) and put them in the loop. The only problem I'm having is the defining the xpath above Nokia you just gave me and other item called ID: 5827165.

Comment: Nvm, figured it. Thanks a lot!